# HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error, while download excel file in vm using esign genie api

Tags: javascript, java, excel, virtual-machine

I checked with downloading excel files using esign genie API. It is throwing an error while running curl command in vm.

Error-HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Any idea you have, if you have used it earlier to download reports.
Api Doc link-[esign genie api documentaion link](https://developers.esigngenie.com/#download_report)

Can Anyone tell why this error is coming as I am seeing multiple errors as output in curl command.

Error-
java.lang.NullPointerException
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

```
    https://developers.esigngenie.com/#download_report
    Curl Command-
    curl -X POST \
      https://www.esigngenie.com/esign/api/folders/getFolders/download \
      -H 'authorization: Bearer <access token>' \
      -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
      -H 'content-type: application/json'
```

```
    $ curl -X POST https://www.esigngenie.com/esign/api/folders/getFolders/download -H 'authorization: Bearer <access token>' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'content-type: application/json'
    <!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</title><style type="text/css">body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</h1><hr class="line" /><p><b>Type</b> Exception Report</p><p><b>Message</b> java.lang.NullPointerException</p><p><b>Description</b> The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.</p><p><b>Exception</b> <pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
         org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:489)
         org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
         org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
         org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
         org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
         org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
         org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:89)
         com.esigngenie.product.web.filters.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:123)
         com.planetj.servlet.filter.compression.CompressingFilter.doFilter(CompressingFilter.java:293)
    </pre></p><p><b>Root Cause</b> <pre>java.lang.NullPointerException
com.esigngenie.product.api.resources.EnvelopesResource.getAllFolderByCompanyAndStatusExcel(EnvelopesResource.java:9423)
        sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7896.invoke(Unknown Source)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:89)
        com.esigngenie.product.web.filters.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:123)
        com.planetj.servlet.filter.compression.CompressingFilter.doFilter(CompressingFilter.java:293)
</pre></p><p><b>Note</b> The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.</p><hr class="line" /><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.105</h3></body></html>u
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an internal error of the website because error 500 is a server error. You need to wait a bit while the developer fixes it.
There is nothing wrong with your request :)